# Casperjs thenEvaluate failing on angularjs Application

Tags: angularjs, casperjs, selectors-api

I have a small CasperJS test script as below. The website used in the `url` is build on angular.

```
var deals;
var url;
var login_url;

casper.test.begin('Paytm test', function(test) {
    casper.start(login_url, function() {
        test.assertExists('form', 'form is found');
        this.fill('form', {
            username: 'username', 
            password:  'password'
        }, true);
    });

    casper.then(function(){
        casper.start(url);

        casper.waitForSelector(".border-radius.profile1",
        // click login/signup button on home page
        function success() {
            test.assertExists(".border-radius.profile1");
            this.click(".border-radius.profile1");
        },
        function fail() {
            test.assertExists(".border-radius.profile1");
        });

        casper.waitForSelector(deals,
        // click on deals
        function success() {
            test.assertExists(deals);
            this.click(deals);
        },
        function fail() {
            test.assertExists(deals);
        });

        casper.waitForSelector("selector",
        // select an item from coupons page
        function success() {
            test.assertExists("selector");
            this.click("selector");
        },
        function fail() {
            test.assertExists("selector");
        });

        casper.waitForSelector(".discraption button",
        // clicked on buy button
        function success() {
            test.assertExists(".discraption button");
            this.click(".discraption button");
        },
        function fail() {
            test.assertExists(".discraption button");
        });

        casper.waitForSelector("#mpCart div div.order-summary.fr > button",
        // clicked on proceed button from cart
        function success() {
            test.assertExists("#mpCart div div.order-summary.fr > button");
            casper.debugHTML("#mpCart div div.order-summary.fr > button");
            console.log('clicked on proceed button');
        },
        function fail() {
            test.assertExists("#mpCart div div.order-summary.fr > button");
        });

        casper.thenEvaluate(function(){
            console.log('in then evaluate');
            angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('#mpCart div div.order-summary.fr > button')).triggerHandler('click');
        }, 'CasperJS');
    });

    casper.run(function() {
        test.done();
    });
});
```

> Every waitforSelector is working fine, but the control is not going into the casper.thenEvaluate function where I want to trigger an angular click event.

I have tested the

```
angular.element(document.querySelectorAll('#mpCart div div.order-summary.fr >   
button')).triggerHandler('click');
```

It works fine from the firebug console, but not here.

Any help would be really appreciated.

Comment: Please don't use `start` a second time. Use [`thenOpen`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/modules/casper.html#thenopen). Are there any errors? Register to the [`remote.message`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#remote-message) and [`page.error`](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/events-filters.html#page-error) events. If bind is an issue, you need a [shim](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10522#issuecomment-39248521).

Comment: I am not a casper bond, So there might be some more errors like that. Changed that but still same. Control not going to thenEvaluate method.

Comment: No, there are no page.error or remote.message. Only the console logs written in code are there

Comment: Pretty evident that it was for paytm .

Answer (score 0):

I debugged the final url call and now I am doing a this.openUrl('that particular url').
As os this scenario it works.

Thanks all for their responses.